# mongoose limit TOP 10 without sort

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need top 10 records, but not sorty it.
I am able to use `.sort('-timestamp').limit(10)` but I dont want to sort it, i just need it as it is.

Is there any other way than reversing the array everytime the request comes?

Comment: did you try without .sort(), just use .limit(10)

Comment: @AnkurSoni, yes, but then it shows first 10, I want last 10, in the order they came.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query to find last 10 records as they appear(**Natural order**).

```
db.collection.find().skip(db.collection.count() - 10)
```

just make sure below 2 conditions('**N**' is no. of records you want to fetch) :

1. **if ( collection.count() < N )** : then you will face below error

   ```
    error: {
        "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue bad skip value in query",
        "code" : 17287
    }
   ```
2. **if ((collection.count() == N)** : the query is as good as **collection.find()** as it skips 0 elements and displays all documents.